# Cypress unit testing show empty coverage object or not find any coverage information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, cypress

⚠️ Could not find any coverage information in your application by looking at the window coverage object. Did you forget to instrument your application?

See code-coverage#instrument-your-application

**@cypress/code-coverage**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What steps did you take to enable instrumentation of the app? There's insufficient info here, but it looks like you need to review the instructions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.